# Bypass spring security for service-to-service calls

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-feign

I have multiple Spring boot micro-services deployed to kubernetes. Im also using Spring Gateway & Eureka Discovery.

Those micro-services are secured with Spring Security and require JWT token for access to the endpoints. Im using `@PreAuthorize` methods etc.

It all works fine when I'm accessing those endpoints from frontend application that is sending JWT token in request,

but, I can't bypass that security in service-to-service communication via FeignClient.

Ideally, my micro-services wouldn't need token at all to call other micro-service's methods via FeignClient. But I still need that security when endpoints are accessed from frontend or when requests are coming from Spring Api Gateway.

Do you know some elegant solution to this problem?

I was thinking about adding another pair of endpoints that don't have security annotations (`@PreAuthorize`) and somehow disable access to those endpoints on Spring Api Gateway, so they cannot be accessed from outside, but only directlly by one of the micro-services.

Comment: `Ideally, my micro-services wouldn't need token at all to call other micro-service's methods via FeignClient` this is simply not true. Best practice is always to have service-to-service authentication, with defined scopes, because if for instance one of the services is vulnerable to a CSRF this could be used to extract data from services, which the original service might shouldn't have access to. You should never trust a client, may that client be a front end application, or another service. This is what is called Zero trust.

Comment: So i would dare to say there is no elegant solution to the problem, because such a solution is bad practice.